# Get location path without parmaters

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way with AngularJS to and get a URL path minus all parameters?  I don't want to grab it out of the address bar, I have a var where the value is a URL that I want the path out of.

Turn this: `var url1 = http://domain.com/dir1/dir2/?param1=123&param2=456`

Into this: `/dir1/dir2/`

This just wants to return the path with the parameters:

```
var justPathLocation = $location.path();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.location.pathname` returns exactly what you need.

On this URL:

> http: //stackoverflow.com/questions/30385367/get-location-path-without-parmaters/30386013#30386013?param=value

it returns this:

```
"/questions/30385367/get-location-path-without-parmaters/30386013"
```

So it returns only the path name, without query strings or fragment identifiers.

---

UPDATE

Here's a regex way, it uses the domain name, which you can hard-code or fetch using `window.location.hostname`:

```js
var url = "http://domain.com/dir1/dir2/?param1=123&param2=456";

alert(url.match(/http:\/\/domain\.com(.*)\?/)[1]);
```

And a more generic approach - `^.*\/\/.*?(\/.+)\?`:

```js
var url = "http://domain.com/dir1/dir2/?param1=123&param2=456";

alert(url.match(/^.*\/\/.*?(\/.+)\?/)[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks!  What I really need to do take an address that already exist in a var and convert it to just a path rather than grabbing what is in the address bar.  I prefer to use Angular if possible but if it's short jQuery or pure JS that is fine. The site uses heavy Angular so that is why I would like to stick with it.

Comment: You're welcome! Since Angular is a JS framework, using plain JS will give you the same or even a better performance. You need a string manipulation, and I think regex would be the easiest way here. You know how to do it?

Comment: Thank you very much, works great!  I'm trying to figure out what the [1] does?  I assume it's for index position but why is it needed for this?  Thanks again for the regex!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad I could help! Yes, you're right, it's an index position as `match` allows you to select multiple parts of the regex using parenthesis, however at the index 0, it's always the original string. To see what I mean, try: `console.log( url.match(/^.*\/\/.*?(\/.+)(\?.*)/) );` Also, here is a great site for testing regex: http://regexpal.com/

Comment: That's great info for me.  Thanks, I really really appreciate your time and help!